# Receber dados de uma url (m3u)

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Tenho a seguinte Dúvida:

***Tenho essa URL:***

```
http://servidor.com8000/get.php?username=NOME&password=SENHA&type=m3u_plus
```

Ao acessar ela pelo navegador é feito o download de um arquivo .m3u até ai tudo bem :)

Eu queria extrair as informações e salvar em um arquivo txt

`Imagem`, `Nome`, `URL`, `Categoria = 0`, `Legenda = 0`, `Qualidade = 0`, `Infor = 0`, `Infor2 = 0`

***1º Observação:*** Sei que em link com servidores m3u não tem o que estão dentro de `"= 0"`, isso seria só para adicionar mesmo sabe.

***2º Observação:*** As informações vem assim:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Bruce Lee - A Fúria do Dragão (1972)" tvg-logo="https://i2.wp.com/asiamundi.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/A-F%C3%BAria-do-Drag%C3%A3o-1972.jpg?fit=674%2C1000&ssl=1" group-title="Ação & Aventura",Bruce Lee - A Fúria do Dragão (1972)
http://xsrv.me:8080/movie/claudio/claudio/64869.mp4
```

Answer (score -2):

Dividindo o problema em tres etapas, pode-se dizer que voce precisa usar apenas as seguintes funcoes do PHP:

Etapa 1: Obtencao do .m3u usando [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)
Etapa 2: Captacao do conteudo usando [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match)
Etapa 3: Salvamento das informacoes no .txt usando [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php)

O codigo abaixo exemplifica como podem ser usadas:

```
<?php
// $conteudo = file_get_contents("http://servidor.com:8000/get.php?username=NOME&password=SENHA&type=m3u_plus");
$conteudo = '#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Bruce Lee - A Fúria do Dragão (1972)" tvg-logo="https://i2.wp.com/asiamundi.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/A-F%C3%BAria-do-Drag%C3%A3o-1972.jpg?fit=674%2C1000&ssl=1" group-title="Ação & Aventura",Bruce Lee - A Fúria do Dragão (1972) http://xsrv.me:8080/movie/claudio/claudio/64869.mp4';

preg_match('/tvg-name="(.*?)"/', $conteudo, $resultadosDoNome);
preg_match('/tvg-logo="(.*?)"/', $conteudo, $resultadosDaImagem);
preg_match('/\s(http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]/', $conteudo, $resultadosDaUrl);

$nomeDoArquivo = 'informacoes.txt';

$conteudoDoArquivo = "Imagem = " . $resultadosDaImagem[1] . PHP_EOL
 . "Nome = " . $resultadosDoNome[1] . PHP_EOL
 . "URL = " . trim($resultadosDaUrl[0]) . PHP_EOL
 . "Categoria = 0" . PHP_EOL
 . "Legenda = 0" . PHP_EOL
 . "Qualidade = 0" . PHP_EOL
 . "Infor = 0" . PHP_EOL
 . "Infor2 = 0";
 
file_put_contents($nomeDoArquivo, $conteudoDoArquivo);
```

Esse codigo geraria um arquivo chamado "informacoes.txt" com o seguinte conteudo:

```
Imagem = https://i2.wp.com/asiamundi.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/A-F%C3%BAria-do-Drag%C3%A3o-1972.jpg?fit=674%2C1000&ssl=1
Nome = Bruce Lee - A Fúria do Dragão (1972)
URL = http://xsrv.me:8080/movie/claudio/claudio/64869.mp4
Categoria = 0
Legenda = 0
Qualidade = 0
Infor = 0
Infor2 = 0
```

E para verificar se as expressoes regulares estao capturando corretamente o texto que voce deseja, voce pode usar o [RegExr](https://regexr.com).

Comment: Eu fiz aqui e deu super certo, mas ele só me retornava um valor. Como e que eu faço para ele me retornar vários valores. ?

Comment: Você quer escrever informações de diferentes filmes no mesmo arquivo? Se sim, basta você ter a lista de todas as URL .m3u e ir, item a item, fazendo esses passos acima, usando o https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php em vez de usar uma string estática. Aqui está a documentação de como percorrer uma lista usando For: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php